# Moving web crawler into background: Resque or Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, resque, sidekiq

I have a Rails App that let the user upload a CSV file with a list(sometimes 200k) of URL to crawl. Then in the controller I will go to each row of this file and then call another method that takes the URL and a few parameters, then when the crawl method is done, save a few variable into a few models. Below is sort of how my controller looks like:

```
def import
  if request.post? && params[:inputfile].present?
    infile = params[:inputfile].read
    CSV.parse(infile) do |row|
      @crawler = Crawler.new(row[0])
      @crawler.crawl #do the actual crawling using Mechanize Gem and set a few variable in the crawler object
      #when crawl is done save a few stuff into some models
    end
  end
end
```

I need to move this to the background (so this process don't hold my entire rails app), and be able to run the code for each row asynchronously. I was thinking something like put everything in a queue, and have queue inside that queue for each row... or something like that. I was thinking can I use Resque or Sidekiq for this? if so where should I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you did enough digging to end up in the right direction! I'd factor that out into a separate background worker system too.

Sidekiq is better-maintained these days, and the multithreading is very useful for your use case, so I'd pick that. Good starting points are [the Sidekiq homepage](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) and [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast), both of which give you lots of information to hit the ground running.

Comment: I have a question, it's posible to have a queue inside another queue? I saw the Railscast and sidekiq homepage/github and the example I see are simple one. I'm looking for something more complex like having nested queues or something? let me know if you understand my point.

Comment: It's not unusual for a worker to enqueue additional work in the course of processing. That's not nested queues per sé (queues are still independent as far as Sidekiq/Resque/whatever is concerned), but I think it's what you want. Going back to your example, processing the CSV might be a job which kicks off a crawler job for each row.

Comment: That's exactly what I want... I'll get into that. Thanks.